# Java - Got Server returned HTTP responce code: 401 for URL: **** while trying to call a WebService

Tags: java, authentication, wsdl, webservice-client, urlconnection

I'm trying to call a WebService with Java.
When I tried to call him the first time I got this error:

> "Got Server returned HTTP responce code: 401 for URL:
>   http://my-intranet-server:7047/my/web/service?wsdl"

Obviously I soon found ~1000000 Answers to this topic.
I tried many.

After I used Fiddler to see why I can access the service via IE but not with the Jar I saw that the IE uses 
"Authorization: Negotiate ************" and not 
"Authorization: Basic ************", so I tried Googling "urlconnection + negotiate" and so on.

**An answer which is showing how to encode for "negotiate" or "kerberos" was nowhere to be found.**

Here's my Code:

```
public class CallWebService {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String params[] = {"0","",""};
    System.out.print(UpdateDocumentId(params, "http://my-intranet-server:7047/my/web/service"));
} 

public static String UpdateDocumentId(String[] args, String url) {
    String retVal = "";
    try {
        url = url + "?wsdl";

        URL Url = new URL(url);
        final String userName = "domain\\user"; 
        final String password = "password";
        final URLConnection connection = Url.openConnection();
        BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String encoded = enc.encode( (userName + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8") );
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Negotiate " + token);
        connection.connect();
        Url = connection.getURL();
        ArchivingWebService service = new ArchivingWebService(Url);
        ArchivingWebServicePort port = service.getArchivingWebServicePort();
        Boolean res = port.updateDocumentId(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), args[1], args[2]);

        retVal =  (res == true) ? "true" : "false" ;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        retVal = "Fehler: " + ex.getMessage();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        retVal = "Fehler: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And here's the full error message:

> Failed to access the WSDL at:
>   http//my-intranet-server:7047/my/web/service?wsdl.
>   It failed with: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:
>   http//my-intranet-server:7047/my/web/service?wsdl
>   while opening stream from http//my-intranet-server:7047/my/web/service?wsdl.

I hope you can help me to find a solution.

Best regards,
Ren Nagasaki

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to your intranet? You may have to add Proxy Authentication to your code.

Comment: No, I'm on a local machine which is in the same domain as the server machine. I'm accessing the WebService via IE without Problems, but can't seem to reach it with the Jar.

Comment: Your IE has proxy configuration maybe??

Comment: No, my IE is a normal IE, no VPN, no Proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, in my case, creating and setting a default Java `CustomAuthenticator` was the solution. (`java.net.Authenticator`).

Before executing web requests, add this line:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());
```

In your `CallWebService` class, add this code:

```
    public static class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    // Called when password authorization is needed
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

        // Get information about the request. Use the variables if needed
        String prompt = getRequestingPrompt();
        String hostname = getRequestingHost();
        InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
        int port = getRequestingPort();

        String username = "domain\\user";
        String password = "password";

        // Return the information (a data holder that is used by Authenticator)
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());

    }

}
```

I got help from [this link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/authenticator/access-password-protected-url-with-authenticator/).